# try-with-resources JDBC with multiple resources and an else statement

Tags: java, try-catch, try-with-resources

This is a method to add a new planet to an observablelist of customers.

I am wondering if I am using the try with resources correctly and if the auto-close is working.

```
public static Customer addPlanet(Customer customer) {
    String query1 = "Select * from planet where planet=? AND universeID=?";
    String query2 = "INSERT INTO planet (planet,universeID) VALUES(?,?)";

    try (PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) Database.connection.prepareStatement(query1);
            PreparedStatement statement2 = (PreparedStatement) Database.connection.prepareStatement(query2)) {
        
        statement.setString(1, customer.getPlanet());
        statement.setString(2, Integer.toString(customer.getUniverseID()));

        try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                int planetId = rs.getInt(1);
                customer.setPlanetID(planetId);

                return customer;
            } else {
                statement2.setString(1, customer.getPlanet());
                statement2.setInt(2, customer.getUniverseID());
                statement2.executeUpdate();

                return addPlanet(customer);

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return customer;
}
```

My question is, does this part need to be enclosed in a try-catch block or does it get closed automatically.

```
statement2.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: The `try`'s are fine, but you should remove the `catch` blocks, so you don't ignore the exceptions the way you're currently doing.

Comment: Sorry I'm brand new to this.  Is it because "Printing the exception's stack trace can be useful for debugging purposes, but the resulting program execution is equivalent to suppressing the exception."?

Comment: Since you catch the exception in the outer `try` statement and continue as-if nothing went wrong, i.e. return the `customer` object as normal, then yeah, you're *ignoring* the exception, since the caller will have no way to know that the `addPlanet()` call failed. Remove the 2 `catch` clauses, and add `throws SQLException` to the method, so caller will see the exception. Somewhere up the call stack, a method might then do the printing of the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

It gets closed. Anything in the `try` gets closed at the end if they are `AutoCloseable`.

Comment: @netcross You're welcome. Feel free to upvote and accept the answer. Have a great day! :)